# How to make UIViewController toolbar appear?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uitoolbar

When placing a UIViewController on the storyboard it has a "built in" toolbar that I can add buttons to during design. My problem is that it does not appear at runtime. There is the property `toolbarHidden` but this did not work to control the visibility of the toolbar. How can I set it to be visible?

Comment: And your question is....

Comment: @DanF my question is how can i set the default toolbar in UIViewController to be visible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "builtin" toolbar is in the "Simulated Metrics" section of the Attributes Inspector.

These entities are available for **design purposes only**, they *simulate* the effect of widgets that may be imposed on the viewController due to external conditions.

In the case of the simulated toolbar metric, this is showing you how the viewController would look if it were embedded in a `UINavigationController` who's `toolbarHidden` property is set to 'false'

UIViewController does not have a `toolbar` property, which is why you cannot find a reference to it in the header file.

Comment: my UIViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController it is a push segue called from a UITableViewController. if I set the toolbarHiden of the UINavicationController won't it effect the UITableController as well?

Comment: @liva You can set it from within each `viewController` on `viewWillAppear` (for example)... `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO`. The toolbar items that go onto the toolbar ARE properties of the viewController.